# Cucumber failures at first time. Second time is ok

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist, circleci

I'm having build issues that consistently succeed locally.The failures are only on login feature specs at the first time, the others succeed consistently for both Circle and dev.

Error: "Net::ReadTimeout"

Partial Stack:
- Rails 4.2.4
- RSpec 3.3.0
- Capybara (2.7.1)
- poltergeist ( 1.6.0 )

It happens at the first time that cucumber run on circle ci.

I have tried to use retry gem and add more time for timeout (180s for poltergeist ). But it still happens. It works fine on local.

Any help is hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is caused by asset compilation on the first request taking a long time.  Try precompiling the test assets before running the tests